# Pigeonhole Principle Rainbow Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

There are 40 rainbows. Rainbows are only made out of up to 4 colors: Red, Orange, Blue, and Purple. 25 of the rainbows have red, 30 of them have orange, 33 of them have blue, and 35 of them have purple. Prove that there exists at least 3 rainbows such that each of the rainbows have all 4 of the possible colors.

I'm pretty sure this is just a basic application of the Pigeonhole Principle, but I'm not really sure how to get started. The holes I have right now are the 4 colors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the contrary, this is an application of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: @player3236 It's both, as pigeonhole principle is needed to prove lower bounds on the size of certain intersection sets.

Comment: can you guys explain more about how inclusion-exclusion is related to this answer?

Comment: @RiversMcForge $|A \cap B| = |A|+|B|-|A\cup B|\ge |A|+|B|-40$. I'm not sure if I implicitly used pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @LorenzaFuller: It’s not: all you need is the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how would I go about using the PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call each instance of a color in a rainbow a *rainbow-color*. The $40$ rainbows contain altogether $25+30+33+35=123$ rainbow-colors. If each rainbow contained only $3$ colors, that would account for only $120$ rainbow-colors. No rainbow can account for more than $4$ rainbow-colors. Can you finish it now?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure—so I have 123 rainbow-colors and 40 rainbows. By the PHP that means there must be a rainbow with at least 4 rainbow-colors. But idk how to prove that there exists at least 3 rainbows?

Comment: @LorenzaFuller: That’s where the fact that there are only $4$ colors comes into play. If no more than $2$ rainbows have $4$ colors, how many rainbow-colors do you get altogether?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're asking? I'm pretty lost

Comment: @LorenzaFuller: If each rainbow has just $3$ colors, that accounts for $120$ of the $123$ rainbow-colors. That leaves $3$ to be accounted for. Can two of them go to the same rainbow, or must they go to $3$ different rainbows?

Comment: $123 - 120 = 3$.    The very most with $3$ or fewer colors is $120$.  But you have $123$.  So there are at least $123-120=3$ that do not have $3$ or fewer colors.... FWIW my answer views this by considering how many rainbows are *lacking* color.  It's the same principal but maybe more ... tangible...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott but a rainbow doesn't necessarily need to have a color? what do you mean by accounting for 120 of the 123 rainbow-colors?

Comment: @fleablood omg I see it now!! is this still related to the Pigeonhole Principle though?

Comment: @LorenzaFuller: Every rainbow must have at least one of the four colors. If each of the $40$ rainbows used $3$, they would altogether have $40\cdot 3=120$ rainbow-colors. We know, however, that they are using $123$ rainbow-colors altogether, so one or more rainbows must have more than $3$ colors. But no rainbow can have more than $4$ colors, because only $4$ colors are available. So the $3$ extra rainbow-colors must go to $3$ different rainbows, meaning that there must be at least $3$ rainbows with all $4$ colors.

Comment: @LorenzaFuller: It **is** the pigeonhole principle, combined with the fact that no rainbow can have more than $4$ colors.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I totally get it now—tysm!

Comment: @LorenzaFuller: Excellent! You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$15$ of them do not have red.  $10$ of them do not have orange. $7$ of them do not contain blues. And $5$ of them do not contain purple.  So at the *very* most there are $37$ that ar lacking colors.  But there are $40$ rainbows so at least $3$ of them that do not lack any colors.